# Why do we assume the total number of valence electron in a compound are the sum of its atoms' electrons in ground state?

Tags: electrons, lewis-structure

Take for example H2O, when drawing the lewis structure for this, we will assume, by adding up the valence electrons of 2H and O in their ground states, the final compound has a total of 2+6=8 valence electrons. We also do a similar practice of assuming charge is preserved in writing balanced chemical reactions. But why do we assume so? Is there any law saying that the charge of a compound's reactants is preserved as they form the compound itself?

Edit - I am not questioning the balance of electrons, I am questioning that why a molecule of H2O has to be composed of its ground state electrons, why can it not be split up into a oxygen ion and 2 hydrogen atoms. I have no reason to believe that the charge of the oxygen, has anything to do with H2O, which is a new entity, in which all I know is it is composed of one 2 hydrogens and 1 oxygen.

Comment: There is a very basic, fundamental law of nature, which says that if you've put 10$\$$ in your pocket, you'll get 10$\$$ out of your pocket. Same thing with electrons.

Comment: Charge is preserved, it has been never observed the opposite. But charge can be interchanged between several molecular entities.

Comment: "are the sum of it's atom's electrons in ground state?" I think you mean "are the sum of its atom's **valence** electrons in ground state?"

Comment: It's unclear what electrons you are talking about, for instance when you state "why can it not be split up into a oxygen ion and 2 hydrogen atoms". An oxygen ion would be missing or have gained electrons, which, given the principle of conservation of charge implies the H together must have gained or lost the same number of electrons. Maybe it would help to include an image.

Comment: @BuckThorn I am talking specifically about the valence electrons. I am confused why in a chemical reaction, the charge has to be the same on both sides. One way to think justify it could be that we start out and end up with the same total number of protons and electrons, so a deficiency (or excess) of electrons will cause the them resultant molecule to be charged aswell. But I feel this is oversimplistic, it would not be too far fetched to assume bonds could alter the charge

Comment: Are you aware that electrons have a charge of -1 and protons +1? I assume as much. Chemical reactions don't destroy or create electrons or protons, therefore the total charge (sum of protons minus electrons) *has* to be constant. Where electrons end up is another question. That can get awfully complicated and is one of the essential question chemistry asks ("*what is a bond*?")

Comment: I think your question might become clearer with a schematic illustrating an example of what you mean. How would a bond alter the charge? You write: "the charge has to be the same on both sides." Yes. Chemical equations are balanced. No fundamental particles (protons, electrons) are created or destroyed. However one thing that can happen is for atoms to gain or lose charge, but because protons and electrons are the charge carriers, the total charge has to be constant.

Comment: @BuckThorn Thanks for following up. I realised my question is more about net charge itself than the conservation of it. In polar molecules like HF there is no net charge, yet they can attract electrons - they behave similarly to ions. So I guess my question is what does a net charge (excess or deficiency of electrons) mean physically. It seems like chemical objects do not need to have a non-neutral net charge in order to attract other charged particles. For another example, take halogens, despite being electrically neutral they attract electrons.

Comment: I created a seperate post for my follow up question, I figured it was too physics related - https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/808415/do-neutral-atoms-have-a-electric-field

Comment: @KrypticCoconut Ok, I understand, I had a suspicion that that was your question. The internal distribution of charge is essentially a quantum mechanical phenomenon. That is a hand-wavy way of saying that it is weird. Electrons are particles and yet they can "spread" themselves about a molecule. You can still try to edit your question to fit this site.

Comment: Your opening question at physics, "If a atom is neutral, does it mean it does not have an net electric field?", is easy: the total field about a neutral particle (atom or molecules) is **zero**. There are field lines emanating and ending at the particle, but the number emanating and ending is the same.

Comment: @BuckThorn Thanks for sticking out with my question. I'm confused by what you mean the total field is zero in a neutral atom. There will still exist points of negative electric field that repulse electrons outside the neutral atom right?

Comment: The number of electric field lines emanating from positive and negative charges is the same, just in opposite directions. If you have an electron and a proton enclosed in a volume and sum the lines crossing the surface they add to zero (where you add lines heading out, subtract those heading in). This is Gauss's law. Yes, there will be lines no matter how far you go, whether neutral or not. But the lines from plus and minus charges cancel so the net field will become weaker faster as you move away from a neutral molecule.